# Is it possible to use Java or Kotlin code in Flutter?

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin, dart

I was wondering if (since I can use Obj-C code in Swift using the proper manners) can I use Java or Kotlin in Flutter apps?

Like import a plugin or framework or just create a function or method using another language and expose it to Dart/Flutter.

Comment: You mean this? https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always use platform channels.
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: this doesn´t work for custom code right? I mean, if I wanted to use my own already made Java code to perform some tasks (that isn't something related to the device itself)

Comment: Yes you could. You just import your code to the flutter android project. Then in the method that you write to execute the platform channel call, you call your old code.

Answer (score 0):

**Flutter's Main Language:** Flutter primarily uses a language called Dart. Think of Dart as the main builder of your Flutter app.

**Java and Kotlin as Helpers:** You can't directly use Java or Kotlin to build your entire Flutter app. However, they can lend Flutter a hand with special tasks.

**How They Help:**

- **Phone Calls**: Imagine you want your Flutter app to make a call.
  Flutter can ask Java or Kotlin (who know how to work the Android
  phone features) to do this.
- **Fancy Camera Tricks:** Flutter might need Java or Kotlin's help if you
  want to do advanced things with your phone's camera.

**Plugins:** Sometimes, Java or Kotlin code is already bundled into handy packages called "plugins" that you can plug into your Flutter app to do cool things.

**Important:** Use Flutter and Dart as much as possible. Think of Java and Kotlin as backup helpers for special occasions when Flutter needs their specific skills.

And check this: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels